# Double click event doesn't work in Tizen wearable? Why?

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I've been trying to get double click to work but for some reason only single click event works. Am I missing some kind of a library or a parameter?

```
typedef struct appdata {
    Evas_Object *win;
    Evas_Object *conform;
    Evas_Object *button;
} appdata_s;

    ad->button = elm_button_add(ad->conform);
    elm_object_text_set(ad->conform, "Hello Tizen");
    elm_object_style_set(ad->conform, "bottom");
    evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(ad->button, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
    evas_object_smart_callback_add(ad->button, "clicked",test_single_click, ad->conform);
    evas_object_smart_callback_add(ad->button, "clicked,double",test_double_click, ad->conform);
    elm_object_content_set(ad->conform, ad->button);
```

```
static void
test_single_click(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
   dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Button Clicked");
}
static void
test_double_click(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
   dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Button Clicked - Twice");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/iot-headed/4.0/group__Elm__Button.html

The button widget dont support double click event callback.

https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/touch-gesture/

Use gesture layer to get double click event callback with more infomation.